# Uget download speed is limited to 100 KBps!

Tags: downloads, download-speed, uget

I am trying to download 2.5 GB .iso file using uget, I sat the max download speed to 0, max connections to 16,but the max download speed that I got in uget is 100 kBps. I tested my connection using [SpeedTest](http://www.speedtest.net/) and the result was 3.5 Mbps for download speed. the drive disk has 40 GB free storage. 
when I turn to windows the download speed reaches .5 Mbps.

Comment: Doesn’t the source server limit the download speed? Have you tried with other software/machine?

Comment: I am downloading Kali Linux . I do not think the server limits the speed.
also I tried to download it using windows the speed was  .5 Mbps

Comment: Could you please try the download with a different HTTP/FTP client, e. g. your favourite web browser, `wget`, or `curl`?

Answer (score 3):

uGet has an option to limit the bandwidth. It's in *Settings* -> *Bandwidth*. I believe, somehow you turned on that option. Check it and disable. To disable, set them to `0`

[image: uget settings]

Comment: no speed limit in uget, also tried limit to 9999KB/s.
uget just got 180KB/s. wget got 2MB/s. download ubuntu iso @2022